# What $n^{\frac{1}{\log_2n}}$ means?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, exponentiation

I was confused with about the $n^{\frac{1}{\log_2n}}$ expression. I am not sure how to make mathematical sense of it - i.e. express it in another way for easier understanding. I tried to plug in some numbers like $4$ and $8$. I got the answer $2$ in both cases. Is it what this expression means? $2$?

Comment: Writing $n = 2^j$, $\log_2 n = j$ and hence

$n^{\frac{1}{\log_2 n}} = (2^j)^{1/j} = 2$

Comment: $log_{a}b = \frac{1}{log_{b}a}$ and $n^{log_{n}a} = a$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let:$$n^{\frac{1}{\log_2n}}=x$$Then take logs of both sides to get:$$\log_2(n^{\frac{1}{\log_2n}})=\log_2(x)$$$$\require{cancel}\therefore\frac{1}{\cancel{\log_2n}}\cancel{\log_2(n)}=\log_2(x)$$$$\therefore 1=\log_2x$$$$\therefore x=2$$

Answer (score 5):

$$n^{\frac{1}{\log_2{n}}}=(2^{\log_2{n}})^{\frac{1}{\log_2{n}}}=2^{\log_2{n}\cdot\frac{1}{\log_2{n}}}=2^1=2$$

Answer (score 5):

$$n^\dfrac1{\log_2n}=n^{\log_n2}=2$$